# certificate signed by unknown authority when docker pull

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose

I set the docker private registry with self cirtification

For now, it works with `curl`

```
curl https://docker.mysite.jp:5000/v2/ --cacert /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.mysite.jp\:5000/ca.crt
```

then I am testing docker pull.

It shows error.

`certificate signed by unknown authority`

```
$docker image push docker.mysite.jp:5000/myapp/nginx:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.mysite.jp:5000/myapp/nginx]
Get https://docker.mysite.jp:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I think it means docker repository dosen't accept self-certificate ?? Is there any work around? or the problem of my localhost(mac OSX)??

Comment: I think the duplicate explains what you need to do: make the certificate trusted and let docker pick up the newly trusted certificate by restarting docker. Or follow the second duplicate to let docker trust your certificate.